# Call a vue method outside a "build" file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The main case is to make vue collaborate with the outside. I have a ready app with internationalization done by vue-i18n. To switch the language I need to change the locale of i18n:

```
i18n.locale = newLanguageSlug
```

The problem is that this app is only a part of the whole website which has its own language switcher. The thing I want to obtain is to change the language in the app when its changed on the website. I am using webpack so the first idea was to export vue as a function and then pass some arguments as props:

**main.js**

```
export function runApp(langSlug){
new Vue({
    i18n,
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App, {props:{
        currentLang: newLanguageSlug
    }})
  })
}
```

Then I invoke this function in **index.html**:

```
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./dist/build.js"></script>

    <script>
        translation.runApp(newLanguageSlug)
    </script>
```

However, to make it work I have to reinvoke function " translation.runApp(newLanguageSlug) " every time I switch the language on the website, which runs the changing locale function in the "created()" instance in the vue app.

```
...
props:[
  'currentLang',
],
...
created(){
    i18n.locale = this.currentLang
}
```

So is it possible to somehow export function changing locale outside build.js? I want to omit reinvoking the " translation.runApp(newLanguageSlug) " function.

PS: "translation" name comes from **webpack.config.js**:

```
output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
   publicPath: './dist/',
   filename: 'build.js',
   library: 'translation'
},
```

Comment: Can't you add an event listener to the switcher in the mounted event? Like this.getElementById('id).addEventListener("click", this.translate); ?

Comment: Can't you just expose the `i18n` object globally, say via `window.i18n`, then when you want to change the locale you can just do `window.i18n.locale = ...`?

Comment: Usually you shouldn't. That's the point of having an app instead of scattered scripts. *every time I switch the language on the website* - why not implement a switch inside the app?

Comment: @EstusFlask You got the point, however I created an app for somebody who is using WordPress as a content manager and uses Polylang for internationalization, that is why I haven't seen any other solution. I should also point out that I am new in vue and webDev so many of my ideas seem to still go the wrong direction

Comment: It's the same approach with all frameworks, not just Vue. You should either expose your public API globally on `window` or wrap external stuff in your app, e.g. register custom event listeners on `window`, so they could be triggered by external scripts. Either way, different scripts should communicate through globals.

Comment: @EstusFlask, you're right. Nonetheless its much harder if you're asked for contribution in the middle of the project. Thanks for your advice

Comment: I tried also adding an event listeners but it does not work @larizzatg. The reason may be me being an idiot but I am not sure. How should I refer to the main window in **index.html** where the button is localised, from inside of my app?

Comment: @13thKID can you make a sample of your architecture? Just mock the outside button the vue app and a vue method to change the lang. Glitch will do

Comment: Here is the sample project @larizzatg: [langSwitchVUE](https://github.com/13thKID/langSwitchVUE)